# Ember How to pass a variable to Ember.computed.filterBy

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Imagine I have a component with 2 properties:
How would I be able to create a computed property based on the localID property and the Ember.computed.filterBy macro ?

```
localID: 2,

data: [
{
    id:1,
    values: [1,2,3]
},
{
    id:2,
    values: [4,5,6]
},
{
    id:3,
    values: [7,8,9]
}],
```

I have tried:

```
filteredData: Ember.computed.filterBy('data', 'id', 'localID') // localID gets treated as a string

filteredData: Ember.computed.filterBy('data', 'id', localID) // localID not defined

filteredData: Ember.computed.filterBy('data', 'id', this.get('localID')) // 'this' not valid in this context..

filteredData: Ember.computed.filterBy('data', 'id', ${localID}) // etc..
```

Nothing seems to work.. Of course if I statically input my value there it works but I wanted it to reference the other property in this case localID as it will be passed from a controller.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your property as

```
filteredData: function() {
  return this.get('data').filterBy('id', this.get('localID'));
}.property('data.@each.id')
```